# VB.Net - Datediff with SQL Field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datediff

I'm trying to do a Datediff in VB.Net thats confusing me.

Basically I'm trying to do the following.

```
If DateDiff("D", Today(), rsData("Start")) > 0 Then
```

This is working fine when comparing the value from SQL with todays date. I however need to convert this to check the current month and if it matches then return whatever I'm trying to show below.

The SQL field format is as follows - 2012-01-03 00:00:00.0000000

Thanks!

Comment: If the SQL column is, correctly, storing the date as a `date` or `datetime`, then it doesn't *have* a format.

Comment: You want to check if it's the same month? Have you tried DateDiff with DateInterval.Month? I'm not sure if this is a SQL or a VB.NET question. And what is that `Today`-function? Normally you would use `Date.Now` to get current datetime.

Comment: The Today function is a property that just shows todays date - identical I believe to date.now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'Is the data's month equal to today's month?
If Today.Month = CDate(rsData("Start")).Month Then

End If
```

Comment: Good to hear.  It would be appreciated if you could accept this as the correct answer.